# Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'mfc42.lib'

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am upgrading My VC++ project from 2006 to 2015. in Between i am getting one issue, its says cannot open file **mfc42.lib**. and this file has not exits in my system.

1. Downloading this file from git but not working.
2. Reinstall the VC++ but not working.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 are both wrong and have no chance of working. The the problem is that mfc library names have changed at VS2015 so the old `mfc42.lib` is no longer the correct library that you need to link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-library-versions?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-library-versions?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Now I understand, so I need to remove mfc42.lib from my project

Comment: Yes, and change the "Use MFC as a statically-linked Library/as a DLL" option 1-2 times save and rebuild. Changing the option should make the necessary changes and include the static or DLL MFC library, of the correct version.

Comment: I have found the changed version of mfc42.lib  is mfc140.lib for release and mfc140d.lib for debugging.  But in my Linker->input I did not find the mfc42.lib. I think it will refer from some different lib file.  how can I find it?

Comment: Could be linked in the code using a  `#pragma comment( lib ...`